# Persistence.js: where are 'require' and 'exports' located

Tags: javascript, jquery, persistence

I am trying to trouble shoot my initial site that uses persistence.js, and I keep coming up with these two errors:

- Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined 
  (persistence.store.mysql.js:7)
- Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined 
  (persistence.store.config.js:1)

No matter which load order I try these two errors come up. I am hoping that these two errors are causing some of my other issues, but I cannot seem to find where they are (should be) pointing to.

I am new to JS in general, so if these are high level js variables please let me know.